# Determining whether a quadratic congruence is solvable using Legendre symbol

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to detect whether the quadratic congruence $2x^2 +  5x - 9$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $101$. I've think I'll be able to detect whether there is or there is no solution using Legendre symbol, but I can't figure out how.
I'll be grateful if someone could point me to the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: very similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147350/determining-whether-this-congruence-is-solvable-3x26x5-equiv-0-pmod89?rq=1

Comment: In particular, you are interested in $d = b^2 - 4ac = 25 + 72 = 97 \equiv -4 \pmod{101}$, and since $-1 = y^2$ is a quadratic residue (because $101 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$) a solution is given by $x = 2y$ for one of the two solutions $y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** The original modulus was $89$. We keep the original calculation. A small appended modification deals with $101$.

The given congruence has a solution if and only if the congruence 
$$16x^2+40x-72\equiv 0\pmod{89}$$ 
has a solution. (We multiplied through by $8$ as a preparation to completing the square.)

This congruence has a solution  if and only if 
$$(4x+5)^2-25-72\equiv 0\pmod{89}$$
has a solution. Equivalently, we want to find out whether $(4x+5)^2\equiv 8\pmod{89}$ has a solution.

The congruence $w^2\equiv 2\pmod{89}$ has a solution. We can see this from the fact that the Legendre symbol $(2/89)$ is equal to $1$, since $89$ is of the shape $8k+1$.

Since for any $w$, the congruence $4x+5\equiv w\pmod{89}$ has a solution, our original congruence does.

**Added:** For the new modulus of $101$, we arrive in the same way at the congruence $w^2\equiv -4\pmod{101}$. We have $(-4/101)=(-1/101)$. But $101$ is of the form $4k+1$, so $(-1/101)=1$, and thus the congruence has a solution.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer !